# Can a dictionairy be a part of a struct in Julia?

Tags: dictionary, struct, julia

I am trying to create a **nested data structure** in **Julia** using *struct* and *Dict*:

```
Struct
   Int
   String...
   Dict
```

Basically, I want to be able to access/assign data in the form of

```
MyStruct.somedict["Boo"] = 2
```

**Code**:

```
struct Teststructwithdict
    x::Int
    y::Int
    somedict::Dict{String,Int64}
end

aDict = Dict{String,Int64}("One" => 1, "Two" => 2, "Three" => 3)

aTeststructwithdict = Teststructwithdict(1,2,aDict)

function dicttestfunction(x::Teststructwithdict)
    print(x)
end

dicttestfunction(aTeststructwithdict)
```

**Error**: Unfortunately, I am getting an error all the time. Not sure what is wrong here, or how I should proceed with error search.

```
invalid redefinition of constant Teststructwithdict

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you listed works without a problem, but if I change (redefine) Teststructwithdict it gives that error. Look for a redefinition of a struct in your code, or restart the Julia REPL session first if you need to define the struct again.

Comment: Thanks for checking that. I should have noted that I was using Julia within *Jupyter*.

Comment: You may need to restart the Jupyter session to redefine your struct then.